# golang variable naming convention across packages

Tags: go, naming-conventions

Recently I started studying go-ethereum and this was my first time using golang. C++ is my main language and I'm a bit puzzled due to variable names in go-ethereum project.

core/state/managed_state.go:25:type account struct {

core/state/state_object.go:98:type Account struct {

There are both "account" and "Account" types in state package, which seems weird.

I've checked [Naming convention for similar Golang variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881994/naming-convention-for-similar-golang-variables), and it still looks terrible.

And what I've found is that they use a lot of "Node" struct in different packages. Definitely they do have different purposes and structures.

Are these kinds of naming is convention and popular in golang? 
If you have any good references for naming convention in golang (e.g. open source projects or books), could you please name some of them? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: hope it will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616687/which-way-to-name-a-function-in-go-camelcase-or-semi-camelcase

Answer (score 2):

> There are both "account" and "Account" types in state package, which seems weird.

There is a meaningful difference between these two names in the language specification.

From the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>      letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the
>      package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

So, taking a closer look at the go-ethereum codebase, here are my observations:

- [type account in managed_state.go](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/5291a2863d27e68310722e2ab9facff438e23cd8/core/state/managed_state.go#L25) is an internal implementation detail, providing a type for [the accounts field in the exported ManageState struct](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/5291a2863d27e68310722e2ab9facff438e23cd8/core/state/managed_state.go#L36)
- [type Account in state_object.go](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/5291a2863d27e68310722e2ab9facff438e23cd8/core/state/state_object.go#L103) is an exported identifier

I think the implementation choice make more sense when you look at [the generated documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/state).

In particular, the [Account type is front and center](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/state#Account), detailing a data structure that's of interest to consumers of the package.

When you look at [the documentation for the ManageState struct](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/state#ManagedState), the unexported fields are purposely not documented. This is because they're internal details that don't impact the exported interface and could easily be changed without impacting users of the package.

---

In regards to naming recommendations, see the [**Names** section in *Effective Go*](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?#names).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chuckx, but I know that the first character determines exportability, but it still seems confusing. What I want to ask is whether this kind of naming is normal and usual in golang. You can find the differences between them if you take a look. Wouldn't it be better if they have distinctive names like accountSomething1 and AccountSomething2.

Comment: Updated the answer with some observations about the codebase.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be better" is a question of opinion (OT for SO) and a question for the project maintainers, not the community at large. If you have questions about the design decisions made by a particular project, ask the people that made those decisions.